# Internal Error In templates

Tags: perl

my TT2 ( template toolkit 2) causes an error due to absence of the plugin, what could be the possible cause ?

the error reads

```
Error 500 - Internal Server Error

plugin error - YAML: plugin not found

Powered by Dancer2 0.159001
```

is there any way of making the message a little clear?

Comment: Check your webserver's logs. The error there is most likely more explicit.

Answer (score -1):

I hope it is clear that the server, which is running Perl with Dancer, is missing a module that is required for the web application to tun. But I agree that it is far from clear from the messages which module is missing.

It is not, as you might expect, either `YAML` or `Dancer2::Session::YAML` but the Template Toolkit plugin module [`Template::Plugin::YAML`](https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Plugin::YAML). Install that on your server and you should be good to go.